# SVG morph animation looking steppy

Tags: animation, svg

I'm trying to morph two vector shapes... but shape is not morphing from one to other,,, it is stepping from one to other... i have animated "d" attribute using "animate" svg tag.. polyline is working fine but custom shape (deer) its not happening as per desired...

Below is the codepen link... 
I want deer to behave like polyline...

http://codepen.io/theprash/pen/MadMjO#

```
<path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M343.5,646.6c0,0,18,4.8,25.5,15c7,9.5,10.1,18.3,9.5,19
    s14.3-27.5,22.5-44.9c8.1-17,21.3-52,28.5-68.9c8.6-20.2,39.4-55.8,49.2-65.6c13.8-13.7,33.7-23.3,45-28.7c12.8-6,50.6-16.6,59-18
    c9-1.5,80-1.6,108,6.3c23.3,6.5,51.5,19.3,51.5,19.3s19.7,10.1,23.5,14.1c3.8,4,24.2,37.8,25.7,55.5c1.5,17.7-1.7,16.5-3.2,16.8
    c-1.5,0.3-8.2,0.7-11.8-5.2s-6.7-19.3-7.8-19.3c-1.2,0-1.7,4.3-2,13.2c-0.3,8.8-2.2,34.8-7.7,52.8c1.5,25.5,25,44,29.5,68
    s-1,71-3,87s-7.5,30-7,33.5s-7.5,13-7.5,13h-21c0,0,6-14.5,9.5-18.5s7-7,7-8.5s-2.5-43-3.5-51s-2.5-40.5-2-45
    c-13-2-32-32.3-41.8-38.5c1,17,2.8,21,1.5,27.8S714,720,713,725.2s-4,23.3-5.3,29.3s-3.8,7.3-3.5,13s4.5,23.5,3.3,24.3
    s-8-1.3-11.5-0.3s-4.3,6.5-4.3,9.8c-11,0.3-21.8,0.3-21.8,0.3s-0.8-3.8,7-14.8s10.5-35.5,11.3-46s10.5-55,8-63s-29-55.5-30.5-71.5
    c-11.8,7-26.3,16.3-35.5,19.3s-51.8,8.3-58.3,7.5c-0.8,11-0.5,20.3-1.8,30.8s-2.8,25.3-2,30.3s5,17.8,7.8,63.3
    c-1.3,6.8-1.8,10-0.8,15s6,14.8,6,17.3s-4.5,2.8-8.3,3.5s-2.3,8-2.3,8l-20.5-0.3c0,0,3.5-8.5,4.3-10.3s0.5-6,0.3-13.3
    s-3-18.8-4.3-29s-0.5-19.8-9.3-42.3c-2.8-33.3-1-64.8-7-71.8c-4.5,14.3-8.5,41-5.3,57.8c0,0-1.8,16.8-0.5,22
    c-5,11.5-8.3,33.3-4.5,48.5c-3.8,16.5,1.5,32.8-3.3,38s-33.8-3-33.8-3l5.3-7c0,0,0.5-7.3,2.5-10.5s5.5-6,5.8-7.8s-0.5-50.3,1-77.8
    s-2.6-47.6-8.6-51.6c-1.7,2.8-8.5,3.5-9.7,1.3c-1-1.9-6.2,2-8.7,0.7c-2,1.8-6.3,3-12,4.3c-0.4-8.6-15.3,20.2-17.2,22.7
    c-2.1,2.8-8.1,15.5-9.5,20.6c0,0-2.9,7.4-3.5,9.9c-1.2,4.4-2.2,8.3-2.9,10.6c-2.2,7-4.4,10.1-6.6,15.7c-2.3,6.2-2,6.7-7.3,18.8
    c-6.3,14.4-11.2,51-35.3,53.2c-3.3-2.3-2.2-16.2-7.2-28.2c-4.3-5.2-9.6-13.9-12.1-21c0,0-4.4-16.3-8.1-20.3
    c-1.6-1.8-26.5,2.4-29.3,3c-3,0.6-13,35.9-28.2,40.2c-26.1,7.4,2.2-10.8,6-15.5c5.8-7.3,7.5-22.7,7.5-22.7s-38.8,11.5-47,12.5
    c-4,0.5-23.5,2.8-24.8-2.4c-1.4-5.4,18.6-4.3,23.8-6.1c7.3-2.5,24.3-8.3,26.7-12c2.1-3.3-39.7-31.1-62.9-33
    c-15-1.3-61.4,11.6-63,5.8c-1.1-3.9,47.9-15,54.6-20.8c4.3-3.8-44.7-43.3-60.7-47.7c-10.6-4-17.5-0.9-38.4-16.6
    c-13.6-10.2,48.4,5.6,48.4,5.6s-2.5-25.2-24.2-45.2c-18.1-16.6-0.8-9.8,4.8-6.7c5.7,3.2,24,20,27.5,24s8.8,11.3,10.3,32.3
    c24.5,27,46.8,49.8,56,55.8c13.5,8.8,57.5,38.8,60.2,35.8c6.8-7.7-8.4-31.8-12-38.7c-4-7.8-23.9-20.3-38-27.3
    c-13-6.4-24.4-17.3-22-22.7c1.1-2.5,51.5,26.2,56.7,22c6.7-5.3,2.2-42.8-24.3-73.9c-21.6-23.4-80.8-24.9-73.1-35.4
    c5.3-7.2,53,13.5,56,6.5c9.5-22.1-6.5-51-13-75.5c26,0.8,24.5,57,31,85c15.5,14,29,46.1,31.5,51c3.5,7,7.6,21,8.5,30.5
    c1,11-0.9,16.9-1,20.5c-0.2,4.5,13.5,59.6,19.7,59c7.2-0.7,21.3-5,21.3-5s-1-3.3-11-9c-10-5.7-10.3-11.7-10.3-11.7s2.3-7.2,36,4
    C357.2,683.2,343.5,646.6,343.5,646.6z">

    <animate attributeName="d" begin="0s" dur="1.75s" repeatCount="indefinite" from= "M343.5,646.6c0,0,18,4.8,25.5,15c7,9.5,10.1,18.3,9.5,19
    s14.3-27.5,22.5-44.9c8.1-17,21.3-52,28.5-68.9c8.6-20.2,39.4-55.8,49.2-65.6c13.8-13.7,33.7-23.3,45-28.7c12.8-6,50.6-16.6,59-18
    c9-1.5,80-1.6,108,6.3c23.3,6.5,51.5,19.3,51.5,19.3s19.7,10.1,23.5,14.1c3.8,4,24.2,37.8,25.7,55.5c1.5,17.7-1.7,16.5-3.2,16.8
    c-1.5,0.3-8.2,0.7-11.8-5.2s-6.7-19.3-7.8-19.3c-1.2,0-1.7,4.3-2,13.2c-0.3,8.8-2.2,34.8-7.7,52.8c1.5,25.5,25,44,29.5,68
    s-1,71-3,87s-7.5,30-7,33.5s-7.5,13-7.5,13h-21c0,0,6-14.5,9.5-18.5s7-7,7-8.5s-2.5-43-3.5-51s-2.5-40.5-2-45
    c-13-2-32-32.3-41.8-38.5c1,17,2.8,21,1.5,27.8S714,720,713,725.2s-4,23.3-5.3,29.3s-3.8,7.3-3.5,13s4.5,23.5,3.3,24.3
    s-8-1.3-11.5-0.3s-4.3,6.5-4.3,9.8c-11,0.3-21.8,0.3-21.8,0.3s-0.8-3.8,7-14.8s10.5-35.5,11.3-46s10.5-55,8-63s-29-55.5-30.5-71.5
    c-11.8,7-26.3,16.3-35.5,19.3s-51.8,8.3-58.3,7.5c-0.8,11-0.5,20.3-1.8,30.8s-2.8,25.3-2,30.3s5,17.8,7.8,63.3
    c-1.3,6.8-1.8,10-0.8,15s6,14.8,6,17.3s-4.5,2.8-8.3,3.5s-2.3,8-2.3,8l-20.5-0.3c0,0,3.5-8.5,4.3-10.3s0.5-6,0.3-13.3
    s-3-18.8-4.3-29s-0.5-19.8-9.3-42.3c-2.8-33.3-1-64.8-7-71.8c-4.5,14.3-8.5,41-5.3,57.8c0,0-1.8,16.8-0.5,22
    c-5,11.5-8.3,33.3-4.5,48.5c-3.8,16.5,1.5,32.8-3.3,38s-33.8-3-33.8-3l5.3-7c0,0,0.5-7.3,2.5-10.5s5.5-6,5.8-7.8s-0.5-50.3,1-77.8
    s-2.6-47.6-8.6-51.6c-1.7,2.8-8.5,3.5-9.7,1.3c-1-1.9-6.2,2-8.7,0.7c-2,1.8-6.3,3-12,4.3c-0.4-8.6-15.3,20.2-17.2,22.7
    c-2.1,2.8-8.1,15.5-9.5,20.6c0,0-2.9,7.4-3.5,9.9c-1.2,4.4-2.2,8.3-2.9,10.6c-2.2,7-4.4,10.1-6.6,15.7c-2.3,6.2-2,6.7-7.3,18.8
    c-6.3,14.4-11.2,51-35.3,53.2c-3.3-2.3-2.2-16.2-7.2-28.2c-4.3-5.2-9.6-13.9-12.1-21c0,0-4.4-16.3-8.1-20.3
    c-1.6-1.8-26.5,2.4-29.3,3c-3,0.6-13,35.9-28.2,40.2c-26.1,7.4,2.2-10.8,6-15.5c5.8-7.3,7.5-22.7,7.5-22.7s-38.8,11.5-47,12.5
    c-4,0.5-23.5,2.8-24.8-2.4c-1.4-5.4,18.6-4.3,23.8-6.1c7.3-2.5,24.3-8.3,26.7-12c2.1-3.3-39.7-31.1-62.9-33
    c-15-1.3-61.4,11.6-63,5.8c-1.1-3.9,47.9-15,54.6-20.8c4.3-3.8-44.7-43.3-60.7-47.7c-10.6-4-17.5-0.9-38.4-16.6
    c-13.6-10.2,48.4,5.6,48.4,5.6s-2.5-25.2-24.2-45.2c-18.1-16.6-0.8-9.8,4.8-6.7c5.7,3.2,24,20,27.5,24s8.8,11.3,10.3,32.3
    c24.5,27,46.8,49.8,56,55.8c13.5,8.8,57.5,38.8,60.2,35.8c6.8-7.7-8.4-31.8-12-38.7c-4-7.8-23.9-20.3-38-27.3
    c-13-6.4-24.4-17.3-22-22.7c1.1-2.5,51.5,26.2,56.7,22c6.7-5.3,2.2-42.8-24.3-73.9c-21.6-23.4-80.8-24.9-73.1-35.4
    c5.3-7.2,53,13.5,56,6.5c9.5-22.1-6.5-51-13-75.5c26,0.8,24.5,57,31,85c15.5,14,29,46.1,31.5,51c3.5,7,7.6,21,8.5,30.5
    c1,11-0.9,16.9-1,20.5c-0.2,4.5,13.5,59.6,19.7,59c7.2-0.7,21.3-5,21.3-5s-1-3.3-11-9c-10-5.7-10.3-11.7-10.3-11.7s2.3-7.2,36,4
    C357.2,683.2,343.5,646.6,343.5,646.6z" to="M485.5,367.5c0,0,0.6,22.1-10,29.1s-22.5,10.1-23.1,10.9
    s2.6,12.6,3.6,14.6s5.8,17.4,17,30.9s20.5,23.8,33.5,28.5s14.8,7.8,27,5s40-6.5,48.5-6.5s80.5-4,109.5-2s41,3.4,51,4
    c10,0.5,19.5,8.2,23.3,12.2c3.8,4,24.2,37.8,25.7,55.5c1.5,17.7-1.7,16.5-3.2,16.8c-1.5,0.3-8.2,0.7-11.8-5.2s-6.7-19.3-7.8-19.3
    c-1.2,0-1.7,4.3-2,13.2c-0.3,8.8-2.2,34.8-7.7,52.8c1.5,25.5,25,44,29.5,68s-1,71-3,87s-7.5,30-7,33.5s-7.5,13-7.5,13h-21
    c0,0,6-14.5,9.5-18.5s7-7,7-8.5s-2.5-43-3.5-51s-2.5-40.5-2-45c-13-2-32-32.3-41.8-38.5c1,17,2.8,21,1.5,27.8S714,720,713,725.2
    s-4,23.3-5.3,29.3s-3.8,7.3-3.5,13s4.5,23.5,3.3,24.3s-8-1.3-11.5-0.3s-4.3,6.5-4.3,9.8c-11,0.3-21.8,0.3-21.8,0.3s-0.8-3.8,7-14.8
    s10.5-35.5,11.3-46s10.5-55,8-63s-29-55.5-30.5-71.5c-11.8,7-26.3,16.3-35.5,19.3s-51.8,8.3-58.3,7.5c-0.8,11-0.5,20.3-1.8,30.8
    s-2.8,25.3-2,30.3s5,17.8,7.8,63.3c-1.3,6.8-1.8,10-0.8,15s6,14.8,6,17.3s-4.5,2.8-8.3,3.5s-2.3,8-2.3,8l-20.5-0.3
    c0,0,3.5-8.5,4.3-10.3s0.5-6,0.3-13.3s-3-18.8-4.3-29s-0.5-19.8-9.3-42.3c-2.8-33.3-1-64.8-7-71.8c-4.5,14.3-8.5,41-5.3,57.8
    c0,0-1.8,16.8-0.5,22c-5,11.5-8.3,33.3-4.5,48.5c-3.8,16.5,1.5,32.8-3.3,38s-33.8-3-33.8-3l5.3-7c0,0,0.5-7.3,2.5-10.5
    s5.5-6,5.8-7.8s-0.5-50.3,1-77.8s-9-63-15-67c-3.5,3-6.4,1.4-6.9-0.8s-0.5-7.3-3-8.6c-2,1.8-6.9,1.6-19-17
    c-0.4-8.6-14.5-17.1-16.5-19.5c-2-2.3-15.7-12-18.3-17c0,0-8.3-13-10.7-28s-5-25.3-6.7-35.3c-1.7-10-2.3-33.7-7-38.3
    c-4.7-4.7-12.3-11.5-25.2-13c-12.8-1.5-34.3-7.5-34.8-20.3c-0.3-8,18.8-7.8,32.7-16.5c4.4-2.8,8.2-7,13-10.7c0,0,18.3-9,19.3-11.2
    s-5.5-27.6-8.3-28.6s-39-7-45.5-26s12.3,2.5,17.5,5.5s24.8,6,24.8,6S372.5,309,372.2,305s-3.5-27.8-0.8-27.5s5.8,19.8,9,24.3
    s14.3,22.5,17,22.8s23-43.8,21.5-67s-19.5-59.2-15.8-60.7s27,51.5,31.3,51.3s28.3-43.3,34.8-59c4.9-6.4,3-38,14.8-50.3
    s1.8,51.8,1.8,51.8s24.5-10.5,38.8-30.5s8.8,1,8.8,1S523,183.2,519,186s-10,13.3-35.8,21.5c-22.5,30-44.8,54-48.8,64.2
    s-26.3,64.8-23.5,66s31.5-14.5,36.8-20.3s16.3-30.5,21.5-44s12.3-21.5,15-21.5s-16.3,54.5-12.5,60s48.5-5.8,72.3-37.3
    c10.3-15.3,13.3-73.2,22-75s-5,46.3,1,52.8c6,6.5,27.3,7.7,74-20.8c12.3,13-58,36-76.5,41c-12.3,12-48.5,39.8-52.8,43.3
    s-20.5,9.5-30,10.8s-13-0.3-16.3,1.3s-53,22.3-54.5,28.3s8.8,20.5,8.8,20.5s3.8-5,7.8-15.8s8.8-10,8.8-10s7.8,5.5,1.8,36.3
    C467.5,383.5,485.5,367.5,485.5,367.5z" />

</path>

</g>


<g id="Layer_1">
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="134.8,218.5 266.5,218.5 440.8,218.5 633.4,218.5   " > <animate attributeName="points" begin="0s" dur="1.75s" repeatCount="indefinite" from= "134.8,218.5 266.5,218.5 440.8,218.5 633.4,218.5  " to="133.5,218.5 268,168.5 446.5,248.5 633.4,218.5     " />
    </polyline>
```

Comment: are you sure there are the same amount of points in both pathes ?

Comment: yeah points are same....  but after lots of experiments i found out that... it will only work if either all points should be corner tangent or all should be smooth tangent... we cant use path which has some points smooth and some corner.... :)

Comment: Well, every segment have to be the same type, if it is what you mean by corner and smooth.

Comment: both are paths with 
"d" attribute.... visit link below... you will understand what i mean by corners and smooth....  i have just altered points from corners to smooth.... and it doesent work....

Comment: http://codepen.io/theprash/pen/wMvqxg

Comment: No by type I mean the `pathSegTypes` or the drawing commands you do use (M,L,C,S,Q,T,A) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adObwN

Comment: oh no.. i don't have that much knowledge about that.... can you give me some links about that... i'm creating these paths in illustrator.. so is there a way to fix that?? or should i manage only with poly line??

Comment: Arf, I don't know if illustrator has an option to force a specific set of path commands. You can [read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). It may be possible to convert all your segments to curves with js though, but that would require a little bit of work.